# Messed up with Blender Animation and Armature and can't see Animation in Blender and GLB export

Tags: animation, armature, mixamo

I have this 3D model with Animations (different Actions) and I don't know why I can't see the Animations in Blender and also not in the exported GLB file. I think I messed up the Armature and Model somehow... Could you show me in step by step Screenshots, what I am missing?

[image]

https://swissmade.xyz/CleanBreathFromOBJ.blend

I am also able to pay if you think this looks more like a "job" and not a knowhow question (not just with this reputation karma points.. real shotter)

Comment: In your screenshot, the model seems to be in rest pose (T-pose), the action "Jump" is active, and frame 22 is selected. The reason why you see the T-Pose and not a Jump pose might be the armature which could be in *Rest Position* and not in *Pose Position*. In your file, I cannot see any problem. When I open your file, the action "Running" is active, the model is in a running pose at frame 0, and the armature is in *Pose Position*. Everything looks good. The Jump action works, too.

Comment: and when you export it as GLB? Are the animations there?

Comment: OK I see thx! I was exporting ONLY the 3D model (limited to the mesh) and now I exported my whole scene and I see all the Animations.. and also thx for explaining me the Rest Position and Pose Position difference! If you like you can make an answer post, also describing what to select for GLB so I can accept your answer. thx <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, the model seems to be in rest pose (T-pose), the action "Jump" is active, and frame 22 is selected. The reason why you see the T-Pose and not a "Jump" pose might be the armature which is in *Rest Position* and not in *Pose Position*.

In your file, the armature is in *Pose Position* and everything looks good. The Jump action works, too.

To export the animation as *glTF Binary* (*.glb*), make sure that you have ticked the animation export option and that the export is *not* limited to the mesh only - *as you wrote in the comment ;-)*. The option *[X] Animation* is at the bottom right in the side panel of the export dialog in the *Animation* section.

Other things to consider (from the [documentaion](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html#animation)):

> glTF allows multiple animations per file, with animations targeted to
> particular objects at time of export. To ensure that an animation is
> included, either
>
> - (a) make it the active Action on the object,
> - (b) create a single-strip NLA track, or
> - (c) stash the action.